# Swift: Searching Firebase Database for Users

Tags: ios, swift, search, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been looking all over the internet and Stack overflow but haven't found anything that I understood well enough to implement into my solution.
There are many similar questions out there but none of the proposed solutions worked for me, so I'll ask you guys.

How do I search my Firebase database for usernames in swift?
In my app I have a view that should allow the user to search for friends in the database. Results should be updated in real time, meaning every time the user types or deletes a character the results should update. All I have so far is a UISearchBar placed and styled with no backend code.

Since I don't really know what is needed to create such a feature it would be cool if you guys could tell me what you need to tell me exactly what to do. (Database Structure, Parts of Code...). I don't want to just copy and paste useless stuff on here.

I would really appreciate the help.

**EDIT:**

This is my database structure:

```
"users"
    "uid"   // Automatically generated
        "goaldata"
             "..."   // Not important in this case
        "userdata"
             "username"
             "email"
             "country"
             "..."  // Some more entries not important in this case
```

Hope I did it right, didn't really know how to post this on here.

Comment: can you please show the firebase database structure, only then it will be possible to identify the query applicable.

Comment: @JenJose Will do, just a second.

Comment: @JenJose There you go, I hope that does the job.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose the Firebase structure is like this

**Example 1 :**

```
users
    -> uid
        ->otherdata
        ->userdata
            ->username : "jen"
            -> other keys

    -> uid2
        ->otherdata
        ->userdata
            ->username : "abc"
            -> other keys
```

And to query based on username, we need to query on queryOrdered(byChild:  "userData/username"). queryStarting & queryEndingAt , fetches all the names starting from "je" and this "\uf8ff" signifies * (any) .

```
let strSearch = "je"
baseRef.child("users").queryOrdered(byChild:  "userData/username").queryStarting(atValue: strSearch , childKey: "username").queryEnding(atValue: strSearch + "\u{f8ff}", childKey: "username").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
       print(snapshot)
    }) { (err) in
      print(err)
}
```

If the username is directly below the users node, then try this

**Example 2 :**

```
users
    -> uid
         ->username : "jen"
         -> other keys

    -> uid2
         ->username : "abc"
         -> other keys
```

The query will be restructured as below,

```
 let strSearch = "je"
 baseRef.child("users").queryOrdered(byChild:  "username").queryStarting(atValue: strSearch).queryEnding(atValue: strSearch + "\u{f8ff}").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

  print(snapshot)

})
```

Please note this method is **case-sensitive** . The search results for search String = "je" and "Je" will be different and the query will match the case.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JenJose ! I'll try that as soon as I get to my pc. I'll get back to you!

Comment: also how exactly do I link this to the UISearchBar? Sorry I'm quite the noob :)

Comment: you have to appy the query in     func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {} delegate method of uisearchbar and reload the table as per the search results.

Comment: the .queryOrderedByKey("username") part says it cant take an argument

Comment: I also only get a value when I type something in the searchbar and delete it again, meaning it only returns values when the searchbar gets cleared.

Comment: can you please give some more details ? I am not getting you.

Comment: The following happens: I type something in the searchbar, nothing happens.
When I delete everything I typed (so the searchbar is empty again) the query returns one user from the firebase database.
There's 2 problems with that: 1) I doesn't return the users as I type and 2) in case it returns something (when the searchbar is empty again as said before) the query only returns one of the users in the database

Comment: did it work ? sorry that i couldn't get back. I suggest you to just check the query first, without searchbar. simply execute the query and see the results

Comment: Sorry was on holiday. I tried to check the query in viewdidload(), but it only returns one user. So far there are 2 users registered. Shouldn't it return all users saved in the database when checking the query in viewdidload()?

Comment: welcome back, a holiday is required in life! the reason it returns a single user is because the Observer was kept on ChildAdded and in our case, we want to fetch all the users matching the given start name. That means, use observeSingleEventOfType(.Value which returns all the values.

Comment: Ok I just tried that but it still seems to be returning only one user. Any idea why? Really taking a lot of your time, sorry for that :)

Comment: it's alright ! I myself faced issues implementing search by name and that's why I want to extend my help.

Comment: I created a demo and checked the above code before posting. I can vouch 100% that this works.

Comment: Ok I'll try again. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: do let me know if there is any issue. or share some part of the DB data, i will check at my end.

Comment: Hi, Thats not working for me, it returned nothing, my data structure is like this , {autoID : {text:hello,otherField:wego},autoID : {text:hello2,otherField:wego}}
and this query ,,   [[[_firebase queryOrderedByChild:@"text"] queryStartingAtValue:@"hello"] queryEndingAtValue:@"hello\uf8ff"]

Comment: @mohammadalabid , check your base node till baseRef.child("users"). Whether it's correct and when you just fetch that node without the querystarting and queryending part, does it fetch all data?

Comment: @JenJose Yes its working to fetch only nodes, already i am using this,
self.firebase= [[FIRDatabase database] reference];[self.firebase queryLimitedToLast:300];

Comment: @mohammadalabid can you post the exact full query ?

Comment: self.firebase= [[FIRDatabase database] reference];
    [[[[_firebase queryOrderedByChild:@"text"] queryStartingAtValue:@"Build"] queryEndingAtValue:@"Build\uf8ff"] observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
        NSLog(@"snapshot %@",snapshot.value);
    }];

Comment: Could it be because of Arabic character values for "text" keys ? could you try with "name" key filter? just to debug the issue

Comment: @JenJose I tested on simple new project and its working!, looks not working when there huge database

Comment: Its working by adding ".indexOn": "text" to Rules, Thanks @JenJose

Comment: @mohammadalabid , sorry I was away! glad that you fixed it. The Rules are not mandatory but it improves the result with huge data. Read more here https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data